# How can I change the method used in Formtastic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I was wondering how can I specify the method to send the data from a Formtastic form.
It usually uses POST, but I'd like it to use GET in some cases (i.e. for a search form).

Is it possible/easy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the :method in the `semantic_form_for` tag, for a normal form_for tag it would look something like this:

`<% form_for :post, @post, :url => post_path(@post), :html => { :method => :get } do |f| %>`

I'm pretty sure it works the same for Formtastic forms.